# Want to update database value from HTML input text without click on button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have input textbox which contain a setpoint and I have table in database have the default value but need If I changed the setpoint in textbox will update the value in the database table without click on button!

Here is HTML code:

```
 <input class="tempSet" id="ACSet" type="text"  value="35">
```

and PHP code but couldn't connect the text box with the PHP to choose the new value:

```
  <?php
     $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
     $DATABASE_USER = 'user';
     $DATABASE_PASS = 'pass';
     $DATABASE_NAME = 'name';
     // Try and connect using the info above.
     $db = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS,                   
       $DATABASE_NAME);
     if (!$db){

die("Connection Failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

     }

     $db_update = "UPDATE temp_setpoint SET set_point='??' WHERE id=1";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $db_update);
      ?>
```

Comment: That's going to be a javascript/ajax solution if you want to send form data to PHP without submitting a form.

Comment: you need jquery for that.. to update database without click any button.

Comment: @tshimkus Yes got it..but could you guide me how to choose the textbox name to be in inside 'set_point='??'` thanks

Comment: @danish-khan-I please could you guide me how to include my textbox input to be chosen from `$db_update = "UPDATE temp_setpoint SET set_point='??' WHERE id=1";`

Comment: Use Ajax to achive what u want jquery onchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery to get the value of the textbox as user inputs value then send that value to the php file using Ajax.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#ACSet').on('input',function(){

  var value = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : {acset:value},
    url  : "file.php",
    dataType : "json",
    encode  : true,
    success : function(response){
      
      console.log(response.message);
    }


});

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="tempSet" id="ACSet" type="text"  value="35">
```

file.php

```
<?php

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'user';
$DATABASE_PASS = 'pass';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'name';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$db            = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (!$db) {

    die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

$data = array();

$acset = intval($_POST['acset']) ?? null; // value from form

$db_update = "UPDATE temp_setpoint SET set_point= ?  WHERE id=1";
$stmt      = $db->prepare($db_update);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $acset);

if ($stmt->execute()) {

    $data = array(
        "status" => 'success',
        'message' => "Data updated sucess"
    );
} else {

    $data = array(
        "status" => "fail",
        'message' => "Updated fail, please try again later"
    );

    error_log($stmt->error);
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: if there is no value I got `0` can I remove the zero integer if there is no value I mean make it empty! thanks for your solution :)